# Открытие страницы по клику кнопки

Tags: asp.net

Здравствуйте. У меня есть две веб формы в проекте ASP.NET. На одной из них кнопка. И по нажатию этой кнопки мне нужно что бы открывалась вторая форма. Есть вот такой вариант:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "window.open", "window.open('WebForm2.aspx')", true);
```

Но в этом случае вторая форма открывается в новой вкладке, а мне нужно что бы новая форма открывалась в той же вкладке. Подскажите что мне нужно для этого изменить. И если можно вариант для кнопки возвращения на предыдущую страницу. Эта кнопка будет на второй форме что бы можно было вернуться назад на первую форму. Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1):

С первой страницы на вторую:

```
window.location = 'WebForm2.aspx';
```

Со второй на первую:

```
window.location = 'WebForm1.aspx';
```

A-a-a, начинаю понимать. Вам на сервере надо перейти на другую страницу. Стандартный способ:

```
Response.Redirect("~/WebForm2.aspx");
```

Comment: Немного не понял куда это конструкция должна подставляться и нашёл ещё вот такой вот вариант: `Server.Transfer("WebForm2.aspx", true);` я так понимаю он тоже юзабелен? а на счёт возврата на предыдущую страницу. Я имел в виду не прямое указывание вернуться на первую страницу а можно как то сделать именно возврат, что то типо cancel. Возврат на предыдущую страницу а не на конкретную. Спасибо заранее.